# Indirect and direct confusion with adjective declension

Tags: adjective, declension

I read today the following line.

```
Vielleicht brauch ich ja dein blödes Geld auch gar nicht.
```

Everything makes sense to me, other than the *blödes*. I feel *dein Geld* here is definite, rather than indefinite so it should be *blöde*. 
Am I wrong?

```
Velleicht brauch ich ja dein blöde Geld auch gar nicht.
```

If I am wrong, how can I figure out if something is definitive or indefinitive?

Comment: "blödes" is right, due to "Geld" being neuter. "blöde" would fit, if the object was feminine.

Comment: The point is that "blödes" is strongly inflected, not weakly as in "Das blöde Geld".

Answer (score 1):

Nominative or accusative singular possessives are followed by a definite/strong adjective. In the other cases or in the plural, they are followed by an indefinite/weak adjective. That is why this particular case is called “mixed” declension:

## Details of *mixed* declension

**Strong/definite endings**

- Nominative singular:

  - Masculine: *mein blöd**er** Affe*
  - Feminine: *meine blöd**e** Schrift*
  - Neutrum: *mein blöd**es** Geld*
- Accusative singular:

  - Masculine: *meinen blöd**en** Affen*
  - Feminine: *meine blöd**e** Schrift*
  - Neutrum: *mein blöd**es** Geld*

**Weak/indefinite endings**

- Genitive singular:

  - Masculine: *meines blöd**en** Affen*
  - Feminine: *meiner blöd**en** Schrift*
  - Neutrum: *meines blöd**en** Gelds*
- Dative singular:

  - Masculine: *meinem blöd**en** Affen*
  - Feminine: *meiner blöd**en** Schrift*
  - Neutrum: *meinem blöd**en** Geld*
- Plural (all genders have the same endings):

  - Nominative: *meine blöd**en** Affen/Schriften/Gelder*
  - Genitive: *meiner blöd**en** Affen/Schriften/Gelder*
  - Dative: *meinen blöd**en** Affen/Schriften/Geldern*
  - Accusative: *meine blöd**en** Affen/Schriften/Gelder*

Comment: I don't know what a 'definite adjective' is, you probably mean a strong adjective. But this is only true for the nominative and the accusative neuter. In "Deinem blöden Geld" the adjective is weak.

Comment: @RHa: My mistake, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_declension):
Adjectival possessive pronouns and *kein* decline similarly to the article *ein*